# Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str' while trying to replace dataframe values with values from a map

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with two different datatypes (int64 and str) and a dataframe. I am trying to replace data in the second column of my df with values from the dict if they match.

For example-

```
Input:
    map = {'Pop': [9, 11, 13], 'HipHop': [15, 19, 22], 'Unknown': '_'}
    
    artist = {'Name': ['Taylor','Kanye','Alex'],'Reference': [9,15,_]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(artist, columns = ['Name', 'Reference'])


Expected Output:
output_dict = {'Taylor': 'Pop', 'Kanye': 'HipHop', 'Alex': 'Unknown'}
```

The code I have in place is as follows:

```
    df['Reference'] = df.Reference.astype('int64')
    out = df.set_index('Name').Reference.replace({z : x for x , y in map.items() for z in y}).to_dict()
    print(out)
```

The issue I am facing is if I don't convert the second column to int64 I am unable to get the mapping to work. However, once I do convert I get a cannot compare types error because one of the fields is a string. Any tips on how to resolve this would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `map` is function and also python code word dont use variable `map`, better is change is like `mapping`.

Then convert `Reference` to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for misisng values if strings, use your solution with replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
mapping = {'Pop': [9, 11, 13], 'HipHop': [15, 19, 22], 'Unknown': '_'}
  

artist = {'Name': ['Taylor','Kanye','Alex'],'Reference': [9,15,'_']}
df = pd.DataFrame(artist, columns = ['Name', 'Reference'])

df['Reference'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Reference, errors='coerce')

out = (df.set_index('Name').Reference
         .replace({z : x for x , y in mapping.items() for z in y})
         .fillna('Unknown')
         .to_dict())
print(out)
{'Taylor': 'Pop', 'Kanye': 'HipHop', 'Alex': 'Unknown'}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a map dict, then apply to the `Reference` column.

```py
amap = {'Pop': [9, 11, 13], 'HipHop': [15, 19, 22], 'Unknown': '_'}
artist = {'Name': ['Taylor','Kanye','Alex'],'Reference': [9,15,'_']}
df = pd.DataFrame(artist, columns = ['Name', 'Reference'])

# create map dict
df_map = pd.DataFrame(amap).stack().reset_index()
map_dict = dict(zip(df_map[0], df_map['level_1']))
print(map_dict)
# {9: 'Pop', 15: 'HipHop', '_': 'Unknown', 11: 'Pop', 19: 'HipHop', 13: 'Pop', 22: 'HipHop'}

# apply map dict
df['amap'] = df['Reference'].map(map_dict)
dict(zip(df['Name'], df['amap']))
# {'Taylor': 'Pop', 'Kanye': 'HipHop', 'Alex': 'Unknown'}
```